# Сигналы и слоты в Qt - разрывать ли?

Tags: ооп, qt, c++

Необходимо ли **разрывать** (дисконектить) сигналы и слоты, если у меня динамически создаётся форма, происходит соединение с ней, после работы форма уничтожается (слот **close** в  переопределении функции **closeEvent**)?
Не получится ли некая "утечка" памяти?
Разрываются ли связи при удалении динамического объекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При уничтожении объекта все связи слотов и сигналов автоматически уничтожаются.

См. Шлее, стр. 54

Comment: Слота закрытия достаточно для возврата всей памяти в кучу?

Comment: Памяти чего и в какую кучу? 

Если при связывании сигнала и слота происходит какое-то динамическое выделение памяти, то при разрыве она должна освобождаться. Надеюсь, что библиотека реализована грамотно. Для большей уверенности, см. исходники Qt

Comment: Я имею в виду при вызове слоты закрытия происходит ли удаление всех объектов с динамически созданной формы? С сигналами и слотами - спасибо, я спокоен.

Comment: Да, если виджет формы является их родителем, все они уничтожаются. Поэтому их нужно создавать с помощью new